# Terminal command ls/cd not finding any files on external harddrive

Tags: terminal, finder, hard-drive, macos

I'm having a bit of trouble with my external hdd and terminal. I've been able to access files on it via terminal in the past, but since I upgraded to El Capitan I can't seem to find anything on my external hdd. I can navigate through it and use stuff from it fine using Finder.

[image: can see things fine using finder]

But then when I try to find anything using Terminal:

[image: terminal]

I'm really confused here — this has never happened before. Any ideas?

edit: did ls -l /Volumes:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    1 Oct  4 22:05 Macintosh HD -> /
drwx------+  2 Shan  admin   68 Oct 11 17:29 ShanStore
drwxrwxr-x  17 Shan  staff  646 Oct 29 21:41 ShanStore 1
```

Not sure why it's showing two external hdds — I only have the one

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l /Volumes`? And you don't have to add screenshots, just copy/paste from Terminal is enough (and easier to read for people on mobile devices)

Comment: I added an edit to the original post with the output. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Now try `ls /Volumes/ShanStore\ 1/Main` :-)

Comment: Can you post the cmd + i screenshot of Shan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, the drive got mounted/attached under `/Volumes/ShanStore 1`. The number will not be shown in Finder but `bash` (in Terminal) is a bit more strict here.

To fix:

- Unmount/eject the drive in Finder und shut down the drive
- Run `sudo rmdir /Volumes/ShanStore /Volumes/ShanStore\ 1` (you'll probably get an error message about a non-existing `/Volumes/ShanStore\ 1`, which is ok)
- Run `ls -l /Volumes` to (hopefully) see `/Volumes/ShanStore` gone
- Restart the drive again